# getting jquery mobile 1.4 to work with bootstrap 3.2

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

is there any compatibility issues i should be aware of ?

I have my webapp built with jquery mobile 1.4, yet for some pages bootstrap give me lot more control over css so that i can make my webapp also works for pc with wider views.

what i did was i used [bootsrap custom builder](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) to compile a version of bootstrap except for typographies, -because bs typography change the size of headers which mess jqm navbars and buttons.

i then included bootstrap on top of my css style sheets

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/ehit/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/ehit/assets/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/ehit/assets/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.3.min.css" />
```

so that jqm styles would have upper hand to overwrites what ever rules it want over bootstrap.

yet before i start diving deep and coding stuff. i was wondering is this enough to get them to play nice together or is there other issues i should fix first ?

Comment: Test them and let us know if you face any problem.

Comment: @Omar so far so good !, i can use grid col-*-* inside any item "even listviews li,jqm dialogs"; also most bootstrap js plugins works fine, there is some issues with bootstrap modals; yet as i depend mainly on jqm dialogs its not a deal breaker for me.